# COM method returning HRESULT value 0x80070057

Tags: visual-studio, directx, directx-12

I'm running the VS project(which is developed with VS 2015) accompanied with Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 12 in VS 2019.
But it threw an exception with a HRESULT value of -2147024809 like this:

```
mCommandList->Close() failed in 
E:\programs\cpp_codes\d3d12\Common\d3dApp.cpp;line 213; HRESULT:-2147024809
```

-2147024809 Indicates that the arguments are not correct. But as it is seen there is not any bit of argument passed to `ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::Close()` method, which confused me badly.

This line of code threw no exception months ago.

Another COM method threw similar exception in `d3dApp.cpp`, which is

```
ThrowIfFailed(md3dDevice->CreateCommittedResource(
    &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT),
    D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
    &depthStencilDesc,
    D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON,
    &optClear,
    IID_PPV_ARGS(mDepthStencilBuffer.GetAddressOf()))); failed in 
E:\programs\cpp_codes\d3d12\Common\d3dApp.cpp;line 203; HRESULT:-2147024809
```

But as long as I changed the fifth argument from `&optClear` into `nullptr`, this exception stops from showing up. Also, this invocation of `CreateCommittedResource` threw no exception months ago.

Comment: Have you enabled the Debug Layer ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/

Comment: @Simon Mourier  I think it's enabled because there is such a piece of code: `ComPtr<ID3D12Debug> debugController;debugController->EnableDebugLayer();`

Comment: If it's enabled you should see extra messages from OutputDebugTrace calls (like in Visual Studio Output window when debugging)

Comment: It shows some message, but I don't really understand it. I'll look into it later. Thank you :)

Comment: The HRESULT you are getting is ``E_INVALIDARG`` so the debug layer is the best option. You should read [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/directx-12-programming-environment-set-up) on how to enable it. Also you may want to look at [DirectX Tool Kit for DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: @Chuck Walbourn Thank you for your suggestions and links! They'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because there is a mismatch in clear color variable, try to set same clear color in all the clearColor variable usage ...

Answer (score 0):

Comments below my question suggested that debug layer will best help in such condition. What I actually did was clicking `Debug->Graphics->Start Graphics Debugging` in the menu bar of Visual Studio 2019. And then, detailed debug information showed up in the output window of Visual Studio 2019, it ran  `D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateCommittedResource: pOptimizedClearValue must be NULL when D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC::Dimension is not D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_BUFFER and neither D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_RENDER_TARGET nor D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_DEPTH_STENCIL are set in D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC::Flags. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #815: CREATERESOURCE_INVALIDCLEARVALUE]`.

So this is the point, because I had set `D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE` in `D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC::Flags`.
It's no wonder that this exception stopped from being thrown by `CreateCommittedResource` after I passed `nullptr` to the fifth parameter of `CreateCommittedResource`. After I had set `D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_DEPTH_STENCIL`, everything behaves well without any exception thrown.

And this is the code snippet ran into problem:

```
    D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC depthStencilDesc;
    depthStencilDesc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    //Assignments to other members of depthStencilDesc

    //This line caused the problem.
    depthStencilDesc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE;

    D3D12_CLEAR_VALUE optClear;

    //Assignments to the members of optClear

    ThrowIfFailed(md3dDevice->CreateCommittedResource(
        &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT),
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &depthStencilDesc,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON,
        &optClear,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(mDepthStencilBuffer.GetAddressOf())));
```